# How to set image from PNG based on dynamic drawable name

Tags: java, android

How to set image from PNG based on dynamic drawable name?

I use following code byt getting the error.

I have PNGs:

```
R.drawable.model_1.png
R.drawable.model_2.png
... and etc
```

**Code**

```
try
{
    String imageName = "model_" + uv.categoryID;
    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Log.e(TAG, ex);
}
```

**Error**

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  you forgot to bind the `imageView`.

```
try
 {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Yourimageview);
    String imageName = "model_" + uv.categoryID;
    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
     Log.e(TAG, ex);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you forgot to `bind` the `ImageView`.

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_id);
```

Comment: You should use `context.findViewById(R.id.image_view_id);` .And it was more better.Because he use `context.getResources().getIdentifier` .

Comment: I assume that he's doing this on an activity. Well that's another optional answer. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    try
    {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        int categoryID = 0;
        String imageName = "model_" + categoryID;
        int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(id);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("NIKHIL", ex.toString());
    }
```